# Android Studio Beginner Question: Why can't I select the correct onClick function from Button attributes window?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, button, kotlin

I am trying to make my button send a notification to the phone, so I made a function **sendNotification** in my MainActivity.kt class.

This is code from the Android Docs which I put into a function:

```
fun sendNotification(view: View){
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
        notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

This is the rest of the code if it helps somehow:

```
val notificationId = 1
val channel_id = "channel"

fun createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
        val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

        val channel = NotificationChannel(channel_id, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    .setContentTitle("Hello from my first notification!")
    .setContentText("Aayyee wassup?")
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Aayyee wassup this is some longer text..."))
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
```

Now, when I try to set the onClick Attribute in activity_main.xml I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAH0F.jpg).
When I click the sendNotification function with the [MainActivity] it just switches to the one above. When running the app nothing happens when I click the button.

Please excuse the rough code as I am a beginner and most of this code is from the Android Docs. Ask for more info if needed. Any help is appreciated. **Thanks :)**

Comment: Open the xml and check the onClick attribute of your buton. It must be: `android:onClick="sendNotification"`

Comment: In which device or emulator use for running code?. Because your code run only on Oreo and above OS. so please check emulator OS version.

Comment: I checked the xml and onClick is correct and I am running an Oreo emulator

Comment: can you post your xml file please?